# Algorithm to Construct Cycle Basis, with the Condition that Each Edge Must be Shared by At Most 2 Cycles

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given a graph ( shown below), is there an algorithm that allows me to construct a cycle basis, with the condition that each edge must be shared by *at most* 2 cycles?

[image]

That is, for the above graph, the algorithm should return me the following 5 cycles as the solution:

```
C1=>e1,e2,e13,e3
C2=>e13,e4,e5
C3=>e5,e9,e6
C4=>e7,e6,e10,e8
C5=>e10,e9,e12,e11
```

Note that not a single edge has more than 2 cycles on it. Any other set of 5 cycles-- as long as all the edges don't have more than 2 cycles on it-- can be accepted as solution.

**Question: Is there such an algorithm?**

I can construct a set of cycle basis by first finding spanning tree, and then complete the cycles by adding edges that are not inside the spanning tree, but I can't guarantee that the the set of cycle basis constructed this way has the above feature I desired.

Also, the coordinates of each vertex are *not* known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching, it turns out that plane embedding algorithm can do such things. One of such algorithm is [Boyer and Myrvold](http://jgaa.info/accepted/2004/BoyerMyrvold2004.8.3.pdf).

Such an algorithm is implemented in [Planar Face Traversal](http://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/graph/doc/planar_face_traversal.html) function in boost library.